# eclipse error cloning git repository from tfs authentication not supported

Tags: eclipse, git, authentication, tfs

Environment:

Android Developer Tools (ADT) v22.3.0, Team Foundation Server plugin, Git Repo on TFS 2013.

What I did:

1. File -> Import -> Projects from Git on Team Foundation Server
2. Selected correct Repository
3. Clone Parameters: Authentication: Use login credentials (alternate credentials not available on my tfs account.
4. Next -> Next -> Error cloning the repository: authentication not supported

Does anybody know a way around this issue without having alternate credentials?

Thx

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio Online or your own TFS server?  You *must* use "alternate credentials" for Visual Studio Online; you *cannot* use them for your own TFS server.

Comment: Thank you @EdwardThomson, that was what finally made us taking another approach on the whole problem. We ended up not using eclipse to manage the git repo.

Answer (score 0):

try enabling basic and authentication security (at the same time) in IIS/TFS